# Plug connector for Knock sensor Mazda 626 2.0L 1998

Tags: mazda, mazda-626, knock-sensor

anybody know where is the connector location for knock sensor? For some reason looking for leaks i see this sensor without his connector but i dont know where is the other side for apply a repair.

Imagen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y1X3.jpg

My car is a Mazda 626 2.0L 1998

[image]

[image]